Why do duplicate 'Curve to mesh' node streams not have identical output lengths?

The two were setup to produce a curve to mesh segment using the same arc.
There is nothing I can do to get the two to equal. My suspicions are floating point error or some values hidden in node with no user access.
I have no clue as to what to do. I can not at this time identify which one is the correct arc length.

The input values of the two Transform nodes don't match. I don't understand what you are trying to achieve with "get the two to equal". More informations would be great.

The arc length is whats in question here. Same arc input to both nodes yet the curve length of the curve to mesh output are not the same.
Without putting another pic up, both arcs start at the same X position behind the icons on the right side.
As can be seen the arc are different lengths on the left.

It's impossible to tell with one picture. Feels like bottom thread is farther away. Consider uploading your file to https://blend-exchange.com/.

They have identical output lengths, that is exactly your problem here. With two arcs based on the same circle radius and the same sweep angle, you get exactly the same length on both.
But you move them slightly apart from each other and also rotate them a bit differently on Z (probably to align the starting points better?), and since they are no straight lines, from some viewpoint this will result in different angles between their respective start and end points, thus making them seemingly sized differently.
This is a sketch how it looks like in your setup:

You can already see the effect which you are experiencing that the outer arc looks a bit shorter, although they are exactly the same and start at almost the same location at the bottom right.
Now let me exaggerate the effect by moving the red arc a lot more, just to the right. Viewed from some viewpoint/camera (black dot) they start in the same location, but the viewing angle width (black arrows) of the red arc is smaller than for the blue arc, making the red one appear smaller to the viewer, although the red and blue endpoints are exactly the same offset apart (shown in green) as the starting points (and the arcs still the same size).

Now what you need to do in order to make them appear the same size for the viewer, is create two different arcs, the one that's further apart needs to have a larger radius. This is the very basic principle of perspectivity, objects further away from the viewer appear smaller. If you do not want to have different sized arcs, you have to live with the fact that perspective distance shrinks objects. Or you have to use an orthographic camera.

By the way, of course this has nothing to do with the fact that these are circle segments and therefore curved. Perspective works on all objects, even right angles, straight lines etc. As soon as there is an offset between them which is not perpendicular to the viewing direction, objects of the same size can appear differently sized.

